# Datastore accessing same entity with 2 different keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am calling an API that takes a datastore key as parameter, I tried to change the last character from w to z, and bam, it answers the same ?! So, how can this happen ? Btw, if I change it to another character, it falls with an expected 404 error.

PS: I'm so scared.

Comment: Which API? Is it using the key's ID, its name or its urlsafe representation? How is it using it? Can you show the code making that access?

Comment: It's the key id, that thing starting with ah5lfmdibC... I can't give you the code because I am not the owner of the API

Comment: Are you sure you're not reading some other entity?

Comment: Can u show your code snippet?